# rails in heroku: one domain, several applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

How can I do to run an application in www.domain.com/folder1 and other in www.domain/folder2, using heroku?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't really do that with Heroku - the system assumes a single app per domain. You do have a couple of options - merge your apps into a single application, setting routing accordingly, or host the applications using subdomains: app1.domain.com, app2.domain.com.